# How to record audio from web browser and download it with JS

Tags: javascript, audio, download, record

I have a small project for my school where I did an online piano.
I would like to record what the user play and download it.
I search this thing and I found some hard stuff with encoding in Base64 and I'm not that good at JS.
Are there any easier thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API) to record the audio and encode it.